# BOOTMGR is missing. How to replace Windows 7 embedded boot files after applying image in WinPE

Tags: windows-7, boot, disk-image, winpe, imagex

I have just applied an image of a Windows 7 Embedded system to a HDD using Imagex inside WinPE. I captured the image of the system on the same board and the same drive and cleaned the drive before applying the image so it's the same system I am applying to. Windows is x64 and WinPE and imagex are amd64. This is from Windows Automated Instillation Kit version 2.0.0.0.

I am trying to place the image on a partitioned data drive which was set as active. 
After applying the image I know the boot files are not applied as I get the message "BOOTMGR is missing" after rebooting. In WinPE I tried

```
D:\Windows\System32>bcdboot d:\windows /s c:
```

The error I get when I try and load the boot files this way is:

```
BFSVC: Failed to create a new system store. Status = [c000003a]
```

Additional info: If I look into Windows\Boot\EFI It contains bootmgr.efi and a few other efi files.

Many thanks for reading

Comment: Hi, I had this problem because my HDD was installed in bios legacy mode and I was booting the windows install CD in UEFI mode. When I rebooted on the CD in the bios legacy mode, the `bcdboot` command succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered after painstakingly researching and pulling hair for a day. 
I was booting amd64 WinPE from a USB 3.0. This was not allowing me to copy the boot files. AS I said in my question, the command

```
bcdboot d:\windows /s c:
```

Would return

```
BFSVC: Failed to create a new system store. Status = [c000003a]
```

I then just burned the WinPE to a disk and rebooted and it was allowed the creation of the boot files. I think it was just the USB 3.0 which was the problem. Even though the port I used was USB 2.0 the USB stick was using was 3.0. Well at least the problem has been narrowed down. No more tears.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for me

***Validate and Fix the File System***

This runs the check disk program to detect and attempt to repair problems on one partition. For example, to repair the C: drive:

At the prompt type: `chkdsk c: /r`

***Repair the Boot Process***

Typically this is used if Windows doesn't start and you can't get to the safe mode menu. You might also replace the Master Boot Record (MBR) and boot sector if you suspect a virus infection. There are four options:

**New MBR** - Insert a new generic MBR without changing the partition table.

At the prompt, type: `bootrec /FixMbr`

**New Boot Sector** - Insert a new Windows 7/Vista compatible boot sector. It will automatically insert the right type of sector for the file system type (NTFS, FAT32, etc.)

At the prompt, type: `bootrec /FixBoot`

**Rebuild BCD** - Rebuild the Boot Configuration Data (BCD). The BCD controls which partition boots. This option will let you select which installations to include in the BCD.

At the prompt, type: `bootrec /RebuildBcd`

**Find OSes** - Scan the system for all OS installations that are compatible with Vista/2008 and will also show those that are currently included in the BCD.

At the prompt, type: `bootrec /ScanOs`

in the end type: `C:/expand bootmgr temp`

---

Play with it a bit, see how it goes