# Boot error with two HDD + UEFI

Tags: boot, uefi, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Dell Power Edge T110 server. It was with two hdd (250GB) in RAID 0 and running Windows Server 2008 R2 Foudation and one of the hdd started to have problems.

I removed the two hdd, disabled the RAID and set the boot to UEFI. I put a new SSD and one more HD (1TB) slave, and reinstalled the operating system. All right up here.

It was then that I needed to connect the two hdds again in RAID.
I turned off the SSD, returned the settings to RAID / UEFI off, I turned the two hds back on. All right too (Although a hd is dying).

I did what I needed, turned everything off, disabled RAID, enabled UEFI, turned on SSD, and windows failed to start. It loops through the system recovery screen or start windows normally.

But if I turn off the HD 1TB, windows starts. If I call, it goes back to the error loop.

I've tried [this](http://www.dell.com/support/article/br/en/brdhs1/sln300987/how-to-repair-the-boot-loader-efi-em-um-hdd-gpt-no-pc-dell-with-operating-system-windows-7-8-81-e-10?lang=en) and this: [BOOTMGR is missing. How to replace Windows 7 embedded boot files after applying image in WinPE](https://superuser.com/questions/891804/bootmgr-is-missing-how-to-replace-windows-7-embedded-boot-files-after-applying)

Now I'm using the `Visual BCD Editor` and the screen is this:

[image]

I'm trying [this](https://superuser.com/a/462596/724641) now!

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the boot loader based on what you've described. Although I'm just assuming the OS is on the SSD. and I don't know what you mean by the 1TB HDD being a "slave" but chances are whats wrong is that when you switched to RAID mode it also switched from AHCI mode to IDE mode. This would cause boot issues and can be fixed by just switching the controllers mode back in the BIOS. It should actually be BSODing if thats the case. Maybe your monitor doesn't show it fast enough.

Comment: @jdwolf, I checked the modes in the BIOS, and 1TB HDD is a secondary disk for storing data. Sorry for bad english, I used google translate. Anyway, I found the solution on the link and solved the problem I described as an answer below. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what happened was the GPT SSD conflict with 1TB HDD (MBR), which had an extended partition that I had created before shutting down the server for the first time. Even if there was no RAID / AHCI swap the problem would happen, it was just a familiarity that went unrecognized. Uncovering the conflict [HERE](https://superuser.com/a/462596/724641), deletes the secondary hd partitions and converts it to GPT too, and the problem has been resolved.

In short: Windows detects an extended partition on an MBR disk, such as a UEFI boot drive, causing conflict. There is a correction [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982929/en-US) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2223832/en-US) but they should be applied in the installation of the operating system.